# CodeIgniter table class loops through db records 3 times - why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

This is my controller code (using Colin Williams' Template class):

```
$this->load->library('table');
$table['records'] = $this->db->get_where('data', array('category_1' => 'weight'));
$this->template->write_view('content', 'vw/weight_vw', $table, TRUE);
```

And my view code:

```
<div class="grid_16">
    <?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
</div>
```

Look at what I get

```
2   1   29  2011-01-01      10  weight      
4   1   29  2010-11-03      11  weight      
5   1   29  2011-05-02      10  weight      
6   1   42  2011-07-11      23  weight // the database only has records up to here      
2   1   29  2011-01-01      10  weight  // from here on it's repeated twice 
4   1   29  2010-11-03      11  weight      
5   1   29  2011-05-02      10  weight      
6   1   42  2011-07-11      23  weight      
2   1   29  2011-01-01      10  weight      
4   1   29  2010-11-03      11  weight      
5   1   29  2011-05-02      10  weight      
6   1   42  2011-07-11      23  weight
```

Any ideas why this is happening? None of my code is inside a loop or anything like that.

Comment: What else is in the table array? I ask cause I see your passing $table to the write_view method as $table when your declaring $table['records'] as the query results.

Comment: @peter, there's nothing else in the `$table` array - should I pass the data differently? I now moved the query to a model, returned `$table` to controller and got the same result.

Comment: how are you returning the results to the controller from the model?

Comment: `\\ the model
$table['records'] = $this->db->get_where('data', array('category_1' => 'weight'));
return $table;

\\ the controller
$this->load->library('table');
$table = $this->weight_model->weight_get_data();
$this->template->write_view('content', 'vw/weight_vw', $table, TRUE);
`

BTW, when I do this on a brand new controller and view, with no other code around and NOT using template, it works fine - when I run it through the template it creates this looping of data

Comment: Do some debugging to find out if a. if the db is returning duplicate rows, b. if the table library is somehow duplicating rows. do a `var_dump()` to check the variables after each step.

Comment: Do you have anything firing in the construct method of your troublesome controller?

Comment: stephen i put this aside for a while and will be working on this issue during the next 1-2 week or so - are you having the same problem?

Comment: Debug debug debug. As Gary has said, var_dump() is your friend. Output everything you can in your code, in the table class, wherever until you find the issue.

Comment: @phil thx, this is in the backburner but i'll be posting back with the final answer

Comment: Also, for debugging - look into krumo which takes some of the wtf out of reading nested arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $this->output->enable_profiler()
```

to see the db queries.

Take the query and run it against your db directly.

It's most likey you have a bad join in your database model.